# Cross join, on multiple columns, without duplicates

Tags: mysql, cross-join

We have two tables with a *mostly* unique email, and a date where a transaction was sent (from one system) and received (in another system):

```
CREATE TABLE `alpha` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_sent` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `alpha`
VALUES
(12344,'loremipsum@example.com','2013-01-01 02:26:04'),
(12345,'foobar@example.com','2013-01-01 04:39:16'),
(12346,'foobar@example.com','2013-01-01 04:43:18');

CREATE TABLE `bravo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_recvd` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `bravo`
VALUES
(98764,'loremipsum@example.com','2013-01-01 03:29:12'),
(98765,'foobar@example.com','2013-01-01 05:42:08'),
(98766,'foobar@example.com','2013-01-01 05:46:08');
```

With a simple join on email and m/d/y of the date:

```
select a.id, a.date_sent, b.id, b.date_recvd
from alpha a inner join bravo b
  on a.email = b.email and date_format(a.date_sent,'%m/%d/%Y') = date_format(b.date_recvd,'%m/%d/%Y')
```

We get every permutation of email+date:

```
| a.id  | a.date_sent         | b.id  | b.date_recvd        |
+-------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+
| 12344 | 2013-01-01 02:26:04 | 98764 | 2013-01-01 03:29:12 |
| 12345 | 2013-01-01 04:39:16 | 98765 | 2013-01-01 05:42:08 |
| 12346 | 2013-01-01 04:43:18 | 98765 | 2013-01-01 05:42:08 |
| 12345 | 2013-01-01 04:39:16 | 98766 | 2013-01-01 05:46:08 |
| 12346 | 2013-01-01 04:43:18 | 98766 | 2013-01-01 05:46:08 |
```

What we want is something more like this, where we join firstly on the email, and then only the dates in an order that they sort of line up:

```
| a.id  | a.date_sent         | b.id  | b.date_recvd        |
+-------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+
| 12344 | 2013-01-01 02:26:04 | 98764 | 2013-01-01 03:29:12 |
| 12345 | 2013-01-01 04:39:16 | 98765 | 2013-01-01 05:42:08 |
| 12346 | 2013-01-01 04:43:18 | 98766 | 2013-01-01 05:46:08 |
```

But I'm not even certain how to approach this?

**Clarification:** What we'd like to do is, emails being equal, eliminate the duplicates so that the date gaps are smallest.

Comment: Given that you are joining on a non-unique column, I'm not sure you can accomplish what are looking for. You can use `GROUP BY` on one of the id columns, but it will duplicate the other id value. It would be better if you included an a_id column in your b table.

Comment: It's time to change your database schema seriously, or near future it will become a serious issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under certain conditions the following query will provide the results you want:

```
SELECT an.*, bn.*
FROM 
  (SELECT a.*,
    (CASE a.email
       WHEN @curEmail THEN @i:=@i+1
       ELSE                @i:=1 AND @curEmail:=a.email
    END) AS rn
  FROM (SELECT @i:=0, @curEmail:='') foo, (SELECT * FROM alpha ORDER BY email, date_sent) a) an
JOIN
  (SELECT b.*,
    (CASE b.email
       WHEN @curEmail THEN @i:=@i+1
       ELSE                @i:=1 AND @curEmail:=b.email
    END) AS rn
  FROM (SELECT @i:=0, @curEmail:='') foo, (SELECT * FROM bravo ORDER BY email, date_recvd) b) bn
ON an.email=bn.email AND an.rn=bn.rn;
```

With the limited data you provided, this works. You can see it here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d6e8/20)

What this is doing is:

- Adding an rn column to alpha... this is some sort of row numbering within all rows with the same email, sorted by date_sent
- Adding an rn column to bravo... same as above
- JOINing the two result sets on email and rn

**This will work ONLY if alpha and bravo contain good data that matches well.**

The conditions are quite strict, especially on the bravo table. In particular, **bravo should not contain and early rows**... rows that match email with alpha, but have date_recvd less than the first alpha date_sent (with same email).

You could elaborate on this and work out a more complex version that works on email, date (day only) and rownumber... as you suggested in your question. But I don't think this is a good solution. I see you have significant gaps between date_sent and date_recvd. If the gaps roll over midnight you will not be able to match rows correctly.